# symbolic link / alias to a database

Tags: sql-server, hyperlink

I want to use several versions of databases (with tables, views, procedures) within one instance of MS SQL server. Let's say I have these databases:

- db_dev1
- db_dev2
- db_dev3
- ...
- db_dev10

I always have a current / stable version and want to create a kind of "link". Currently, "db_dev2" is stable and I want a "link" or alias "db_stable" and use all the tables, procedures,... of "db_dev2" but using the name "db_stable". In a filesystem like NTFS or EXT4 I would create a symbolic link. **How can I do it within MS SQL server?** When developments continues I would change the "link" to "db_dev3" and so on. Doing this I do not have to change the SQL code that access this database(s).

A workaround with a "hardlink" -- a copy of "db_dev2" to be renamed as "db_stable" -- would be no good solution for me since the databases are quite big.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. Certainly, if you were to create symbolic links, you would have take the databases effected offline, change the link(s), and then put them back online; which is hardly ideal. Honestly, having multiple, swappable, copies of a database sounds like a major design/workflow flaw.

Comment: It is not my design. How would you design databases with developments in time?

Comment: Depends what you're doing. I suspect this is something a "couple" of extra instances or good source control and migration processes would solve (probably the latter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use synonyms. Unfortunately you cannot create a synonym for a database.
But you can create a "empty" database db_stable that has synonyms for all the objects. 
Just write some script to create/alter the synonyms for every object.